# How to integrate iPod in my app as a shortcut?

Tags: iphone, integration, ipod

I want to show iPod as a shortcut in my app, to convenient users, they can click it to invoke real iPod app. How can I do it? Any code I can take reference? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5 you can call:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]]){     
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys, work well on IOS 5.